# PHP mail won't send when there is a url a tag in the body

Tags: php, email

```
                   <?php
                   // multiple recipients

                     $to = 'ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com';

                       // subject
                   $subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

                // message
               $message = '<html>
              <head></head>
                  <body>Content here and <a href="http://www.google.com">this</a> is              a                      link</body>
                 </html>';

               // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

         // Additional headers
             $headers = 'To: Mary <ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
             $headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

           $headers  .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
           $headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
           $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";

             echo "To : ".$to;

            // Mail it
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

              ?>
```

please solved this . when i added Download in the mail body mail not send.

if i remove this a tag mail sent and all other content display as per my requirement .

I dont know where is the exact problem, i m using godady hosting with PHP 5.3 version.

if any one have better solutions please share with me .

Comment: which mailer function you are using ?

Comment: Show us some code please?

Comment: Are you sur the mail is not sent, or does it just go into spam folder ?

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted your code a little bit. Main change is in From: header - `$header = "From: \"HCS Support Team\" <$from_id>\r\n" . "Reply-To: $from_id\r\n";`

```
$erm.= '<TR>
            <TD WIDTH="50%">' . "Download-" . $j . '</TD>
            <TD WIDTH="50%"><a href="http://xyz.com' . $path . '">Download</a></TD>
        </TR>';


$from_id = "support@xyz.com";
$header = "From: \"HCS Support Team\" <$from_id>\r\n" . "Reply-To: $from_id\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$subject = "Request for Case Study Solution Received";
@mail("ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com", $subject, $erm, $header);
```

It seems the mail is being sent, but it goes straight to **SPAM** folder. Please read about spam rules which make the mails go to spam folder: http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_3_x.html

In your case the main problem with gmail is probably it's being sent with standard PHP mail function. Please try [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) or [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected).

The rules which are met by spamassasin in your mail are:

- **HTML_MESSAGE**
- **HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG**
- **MIME_HTML_ONLY**

Comment: yes i m sure mail is not send. if i remove a href www.xyz.com then mail sent

Comment: Then remove "@" from before function mail and look for any error. Also you can save the return of mail to some variable and check the result. 
Example:
    `$result = mail("ali.dzinemedia@gmail.com", $subject, $erm, $header);
    echo $result;`

Please tell us what is the result then and if there are any errors or warnings.

Comment: Yes, that means the mail is sent. Are you sure it's not in the spam folder?

Comment: yes sure mail sent but not come in spam folder or inbox ... i dont know where is the problem. if i remove <TD WIDTH="50%"><a href="http://xyz.com' . $path . '">Download</a></TD>  line from the mail body mail send and every thing worked perfectly . Right now mail script does not pick the http://www. or href from the mail body although i have already set content-type : html/text already set

Comment: Are you sure you have the code exactly like mine? Cause in the line you just copied there is a syntax error - it should be `<TD WIDTH="50%"><a href="xyz.com' . $path . '">Download</a></TD>`
And let us see your `$path` variable

Comment: What are the contents of your $path variable? Can you try this link: `<TD WIDTH="50%"><a href="https://google.com">Download</a></TD>`

Comment: ok let me try this , in $path variable is the /uploads/abc.png $path contain folder path nothing else

Comment: still not working i dont know where is the problem i checked every single line of the code .

Comment: now i set this line like this . <TD WIDTH="50%"><a href=xyz.com>Download</a></TD> . Now the mail goes in spam ,

Comment: Then it's a good thing. If you could edit your first post and add all the contents of the PHP file, that would help.

Comment: @user2731816 Please stop wasting peoples' time and read a tutorial, learn how to debug your code, and work out how to use the language properly

Comment: what do you mean by use language properly ?

Comment: It means - learn the basics yourself, we are here not as your teachers, but to solve particular problems